# Bitwise operation SQL

Tags: sql, binary, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bitwise-and

Hi I'm using SQL Server Management Studio and need a little light shed on bitwise operations.

I've got certain values to determine users access rights e.g.

1 - View Document
2 - View Object
4 - View Rules
8 - Edit Document
16 - Edit Object
32 - Edit Rule
64 - Delete Document
128 - Delete Object
256 - Delete Rules.

Currently within the database the value for the user's access rights are stored within the database as a bitwise operator 
e.g. 73 - Which means the user can View, Documents, Edit, Documents and Delete Documents.

How can I write a query to bring up users details and interpret the integer stored within the accessRights field to display:

"View Document" + "Edit Document" + "Delete Document"

In a custom Column "Users" rights.

I tried using the case when access level = 1 "One's Properties"... when access level equals 2 "Two's properties" .... when access level equals 3 "Ones Properties" + "Two's properties"

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend it because of performance reasons (you cannot use indexes for querying if having to perform bitwise type operations on the column for example)...

But the bitwise OR in SQL (well, T-SQL/Sql Server) is `|` and the bitwise and is `&`.

Comment: I agree the consideration for performance and I don't recommend also. The only exception of this is for some reason for compatibility and in case that this value will not participate in where clause.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand your response, how can I go about representing the users rights then?

Comment: The relational-database method is to make a table with UserRights, a table with Users and then have an table tying the two together with User, Rights (UserToUserRights)
Then it's a simple check to see if the User exists in that table with the correct rights.